# CSS menu: Word wrap in sub menus

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, word-wrap, css

I have a CSS dropdown menu, but I can't figure out one problem. Everything after the first level has a strange word wrap behavior that I don't want. It probably has something to do with the `position` and `display` properties but I just can't figure it out.

This is how it looks at the moment:
[image]

This is how I want it to look:
[image]

Giving the element a fixed with fixes this problem, but I don't want to do that.

My CSS code for the menu looks like this:

```
.menuclass {
  background: grey;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menuclass li {
  float: left;
}

.menuclass li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.menuclass ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

.menuclass ul li {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menuclass ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**What can I do to fix this problem?**

I found a similar question where it was recommended to use `white-space: nowrap;` but somehow this seems a bit funky to me.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hSVrc/)

Comment: you'll probably need `white-space: nowrap`. If you set up a fiddle I would be happy to demonstrate

Comment: @PeterVR I added the link to a Fiddle to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `.menuclass ul li` selector.

Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/hSVrc/1/